# In react form, cannot type in text fields or click or hover over button

Tags: css, reactjs, hover

I'm new to React and am creating a login page that `requires a username and password.` I haven't added much of the logic yet but from what I've seen online, I should at least be `able to click on the text fields` or be `able to hover over the sign-in button` and see some changes.

I've added hover `CSS` that I have to forcefully trigger in `Google DevTools` to see any changes. Hoping I can get some help with this. The code is as follows:-

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return (
                    <form>

                            <SmallHeading name="USERNAME:"/>
                            <input className="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Enter username"/>

                            <div className="space"></div>

                            <SmallHeading name="PASSWORD:"/>
                            <input className="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Enter password"/>

                            <div id="buttonWrapper">
                                    <input type="submit" className="btn buttonFont buttonStyle" id="logInButton" value="LOG IN" />
                            </div>
                    </form>
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: what changes are expecting. the input value change?

Comment: as i can see it is working fine on code sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-v10ig. maybe your SmallHeading component is creating problem please try removing that component.

Comment: @VipinYadav as of now I just want to be able to hover over the button and see the change as per the CSS. The text boxes should be clickable too.

Comment: @VipinYadav removing the SmallHeading component does not change anything. Not sure what's happening here. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - a very silly mistake on my end. After debugging further, I discovered the problem was in the CSS of the div in which the form resides. I'd set the z-index to -1 and that was interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Simple login form

```
class Login extends Component {
  state={
    username:'',password:''
  }
  onChange=e=>{
    let val = e.target.value
    this.setState({[e.target.name]:val})
  }
  handleSubmit=e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const {username} = this.state;
    alert(username)
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <label>Username</label>
        <input
          className="username"
          name='username'
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter username"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          className="password"
          name='password'
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter password"
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="btn buttonFont buttonStyle"
            id="logInButton"
            value="LOG IN"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

css

```
input[type=text]{ 
        width: 100%; 
        padding: 12px 20px; 
        margin: 8px 0; 
        display: inline-block; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        box-sizing: border-box; 
    } 
input[type=submit] { 
      background-color: #4CAF50; 
      color: white; 
      padding: 14px 20px; 
      margin: 8px 0; 
      border: none; 
      cursor: pointer; 
      width: 100%; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add hover to button

```
input[type=submit]:hover{
  color: red
}
```

or for wrpper

```
#buttonWrapper:hover{
  color: red
}
```

hop be helpfull
[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-over-button-m1edz)

Comment: It's not working. :/ The same issue persists. When I use Chrome DevTools and force element change, then I can see what happens on hover. Otherwise it is not working.

Comment: please attach your CSS